# AWS cloudwatch dynamically list metrics and there infomation

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sdk, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

Right, so I am trying to get a list of `metric_names` for a particular namespace (I'd rather it be for an object, but I'm working with what I've got) using AWS Ruby sdk, and cloudwatch has the `list_metrics` function, awesome!..

Except that `list_metrics` doesn't return what unit's and statistics a metric supports which is a bit stupid as you need both to request data from a metric.

If you're trying to dynamically build a list of metrics per namespace (which I am) you won't know what unit's or statistics a particular metric might support without knowing about the metrics before hand which makes using `list_metrics` to dynamically get a list of metrics pointless.

How do I get around this so I can build a hash in the correct format containing the metrics for any namespace without knowing anything about a metric before hand except for the hash structure.

Also why is there not a query for what metrics an object (dynamo,elb,etc) has?

It seems a logical thing to have because a metric does not exist for an object unless it's actually spat out data for that metric at least once (so I've been told); which means even if you have a list of all the metrics a namespace supports, it doesn't mean that an object within the namespace will have those metrics.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch is a very general-purpose tool, with a generic schema for all metric data in the [MetricDatum structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDatum.html).  But individual metrics have no schema other than the data sent in practice.

So there is no object for Dynamo, EC2, etc. that projects what metrics might be sent.  There is only metric data that has already been sent with a particular namespace.  [Amazon CloudWatch Namespaces, Dimensions, and Metrics Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CW_Support_For_AWS.html) documents the metric schema for many or all of the metrics AWS services capture.  I know that's not what you wanted.

You can query any CloudWatch metric support by any of the statistics tracked by CloudWatch (SampleCount, Minimum, Maximum, Average, and Sum).  CloudWatch requires that incoming metric data either include all statistics or with raw values that allow the statistics to be calculated.

I don't know of any way to get the units other than to query the data and look through what is returned.